# Slightly different ESLint configuration per Angular module

Tags: angular, eslint, angular-components

In our Angular project we had some files in their own Angular library. Each of those libraries had their own `.eslintrc.json` and `package.json`, which both extended from our main ones, with some custom overwrites. One of the overwrites in the `.eslintrc.json` was for the prefix of components' selectors.

Since we moved away from Angular libraries for various reasons and they're all Angular modules now, we only have a single main `.eslintrc.json` and `package.json`.
For now we simply have a list of all allowed prefixes in this single `.eslintrc.json` like this:

```
"@angular-eslint/component-selector": [
  "error",
  {
    "type": "element",
    "prefix": ["prefix-a","prefix-b","prefix-c"],
    "style": "kebab-case"
  }
],
```

with the following in our `angular.json`:

```
{
  ...,
  "projects": {
    "front-end": {
      ...,
      "prefix": "prefix-a",
      ...
```

If we generate a new component, it'll get this `prefix-a` as prefix, whichever module we add it in. Since we can't enforce it through the `angular.json` (as far as I know; if someone knows how to have multiple `"prefix"`es per Angular module in the `angular.json`, let me know), we'd at least like to enforce it through ESLint errors.

Does anyone know whether it's possible to have an `.eslintrc.json` per Angular module, extending from the main `.eslintrc.json`, but each with its own single allowed custom `prefix` for its component-selectors?

Comment: Presumably your modules have their own directories, in which case https://eslint.org/docs/latest/use/configure/configuration-files#configuration-based-on-glob-patterns.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Sorry for the late response. I've just tried your suggested solution today, and it indeed works, so thanks. Feel free to make this comment into an actual answer, then I'll accept (and upvote) it. :)